# How a function that return an Int can be part of if statement?

Tags: android, if-statement, kotlin, boolean

I have define a new function (please don't refer to the logic, only if it is necessary):

```
 operator fun Int?.compareTo(other: Int): Int
        {
            if (this == null)
                return -1
            if (this > other)
                return 1
            else return 0

        }
```

now in an if statment i'm writing:

```
 val x:Int? =8
 if(... && .... && ...&& x > 5)
```

I see that the *x>5* runs the function I wrote above (*compare*), but this function doesn't return a Boolean, it returns an Int. So how can it compiled although one of the condition  isn't a boolean?

Comment: `if((... && .... && ...&& x) > 5)`

Comment: @blackapps, didn't understand you.

Comment: I could not see what you are anding and comparing either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#comparison) (at the end of the page), you can see that `a > b` uses compareTo, but it actually translate to `a.compareTo(b) > 0`.

So `if(... && x > 5)` is implicitly `if(... && x.compareTo(5) > 0)`, and that's why you can use it in a if statement

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also the *fun operator* i'm creating, will be compared in the end with 0?

Comment: That's right. The return of the fun operator compareTo will compared with 0.

So a > b will be true if compareTo returns a positive values, a >= b will be true if compareTo returns zero or positive, and so on...